# Modify Azure TCP Idle Timeout load-balancer for VM cloud server

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service, powershell-3.0

I am trying to extend the default TCP timeout in the azure server. (VM)

1. Is it possible to do this within the Azure portal?
2. Is it possible to remotely connect to the server & configure it within the administrative tools, or registry, or using the cmd commands.
3. Is this possible to modify the TCp timout only by using the powershell? if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check this URL https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/load-balancer-tcp-idle-timeout/ Since you are using a single VM (not a load balanced set) you can configure TCP timeout for your Instance-Level Public IP using Azure PowerShell